# getting information from a webpage for an application using python

Tags: python, html, xml

I am currently trying to create  a bot for the betfair trading site, it involves using the betfair api which uses soap and the new API-NG will use json so I can  understand how to access the information that I need. 
My question is, using python, what would the best way to get information from a website that uses just html, can I convert it some way to maybe xml or what is the best/easiest way.
Json, xml and basically all this is new to me so any help will be appreciated.
This is one of the websites I am trying to access to get horse names and prices,

> http://www.oddschecker.com/horse-racing-betting/chepstow/14:35/winner

I know there are some similar questions but looking at the answers and the source of the above page I am no nearer to figuring out how to get the info I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting html from a website there are two well used options.

[urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html) This is built in.

[requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) This is third party but really easy to use.

If you then need to parse your html then I would suggest using [Beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.example.com'
page_request = requests.get(url)
page_source = page_request.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source)
```

The page_source is just the basic html of the page, not much use, the soup object on the other hand can be used to access different parts of the page automatically.

Comment: thanks, is there any advantage in relation to speed on which library to use  or on converting the  html to xml?

Comment: I don't think there is any speed improvement to be had by using urllib2 over requests.  As to converting html to xml I don't know, it's not something I've ever done.